# Cannot render php queried page in any Mac OSX Mountain 10.8 browser

Tags: php, macos

I am having trouble viewing the content of http://www.mysipo.com/sys/exam/outline.php?id=2.1.3#2.1.3, followed by clicking on any of the red links (see the attached google drive picture below). I have tried safari, firefox, and google chrome to no avail.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9qvt2SGs7BYRjZIeWt3OEJBams

This works on PC with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You've some bugs in your code. The first 4 occurred while loading the page, the last one as i clicked the red link. To give more help, we need at least some more information (code etc.)

(Right-click and open image in new tab for an larger version)

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

Comment: I appreciate your quick reply and debugging. I have no access to the html or php code as I am only a visitor to the website. I am curious why browsers on PC were able to overlook these bugs.